# Does something bad happen if I keep a pointer to a ref struct in another ref struct in C#

Tags: c#, struct, ref

So I want to wrap a ref struct, specifically a SequenceReader, into another ref struct.

I came up with this:

```
public ref struct PropertyAccessor
{
    private unsafe readonly SequenceReader<byte>* data;
    private unsafe ref SequenceReader<byte> Data => ref *data;

    internal unsafe PropertyAccessor(ref SequenceReader<byte> data)
    {
        fixed (SequenceReader<byte>* datePtr = &data)
        {
            this.data = datePtr;
        }
    }
}
```

To get around the restriction on ref fields in ref structs. (CS9050)

This results in a bunch of CS5800 warnings.

```
     Warning CS8500: This takes the address of, gets the size of, or declares a pointer to a managed type ('SequenceReader<byte>')
```

What bad happens if I do this?  The compiler has done a lot of work to make this hard (but not impossible to do.)  Note that both SequenceReader and PropertyAccessor are ref structs that can only exist on the stack.  The sequence reader must be higher on the stack than the PropertyAccessor because it exists at the time that PropertyAccessor's constructor gets called.  Since they are both on the stack and going to stay there SequenceReader cannot move and it has to last longer than PropertyAccessor.

Is this a case where I can safely ignore the warning?

Comment: [The unsafe keyword denotes an unsafe context, which is required for any operation involving pointers. For more information, see Unsafe Code and Pointers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe).  So you can never "safely" ignore it, because you use `unsafe`.

Comment: I guess you need to study pointers and their use cases first in a another language that generally allows usage of pointers. A pointer to another pointer is not something bad or sign of bad design, as we practiced that in C before and we still do in Go. But you have to be careful about something called Dangling Pointers. In C#, it's not exactly the same, but the programming theory behind it is still valid.

Comment: You're saying because `SequenceReader` exists before `PropertyAccessor` it could never get popped before `PropertyAccessor`. You may very well be right about that.  In fact you may very well be right overall and the compiler is giving you a *warning* but still letting you do it because it's not *per se* wrong. Not gonna lie, though, it feels icky.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I've programmed in C# for 20 years and I think I used `unsafe` once. There's probably a more C#-y way to do whatever it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm with @Flydog57 on this one. I've been doing C# for about 18 years, and have never needed to use `unsafe`. It would be helpful if you explained what you are actually trying to do, as there may be an easier/safer way to do it.

Comment: I'm completely confused about why you need pointers at all here. Why not just declare the field `private readonly SequenceReader<byte> data;`

Comment: What I want to do is I want a struct that you can read from, and the original sequence reader which created the struct will be incremented when data is read from the wrapping struct.  (Think of like a struct to read a stream one bit, rather than one byte, at a time.)  This feature was scheduled to be included in C# 11 (ref fields in ref structs) but then they took back this limited case -- a ref field to a ref struct, hence the need for the hack above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements#ref-fields-to-ref-struct , I expect the problem to be not with the `SequenceReader<byte>` itself but with the `ref`s it contains. The expectation would be that these `ref`s (probably `Span<byte>`) point only to data in the passed `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` instance(s) and therefore not to the stack, but it is not entirely certain that this is indeed the case (for example, it will be a problem if a new version of `SequenceReader<>` adds the ability to read from a `Span<>`). It is also possible that the code is sound now but will be unsound or unusable when a new version of C# adds ref fields to ref struct in an unexpected way.

I suggest not using `unsafe`, but instead one of these alternatives:

- Store the `SequenceReader<byte>` as a field and have the caller extract it or its `UnreadSequence` property when done (the latter might allow hiding the fact that `SequenceReader<byte>` is being used).
- Don't have `PropertyReader` as a `ref struct` at all, but provide its functionality as methods taking a `ref SequenceReader<byte>`. These methods could be static methods or instance methods.